# Getting Error while connecting to DB using c#

Tags: c#, sql

Is there anything wrong with this code? Please help me out.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string cs = "Data Source=SFSIND0402;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand insert = conn.CreateCommand();
        insert.CommandText="insert into Employee(ID, Name, Sex, Salary) values('003','Vedpathi','M',25000)";
        insert.Connection = conn;
        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

(on line 22:conn.Open();)

Comment: What kind of database server are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Is Your provider correct? It seems to me, that You try to connect to Access. The provider should be SQLNCLI10. Isn't it?

Comment: Then why are you using an MS ACCESS OLEDB connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting to an MS SQL database, use the MS SQL providers:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();

  var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution [Luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) mentioned, you should store your connection string in the config file of the app and also encrypt it.

Even if you use SSL encryption when communicating with the DB, an ill-indended person can extract the string variables, if he / she runs the application on his / her machine.